# Why is UHF so much more popular than other frequencies for radio?

Tags: radio-frequency

Great most of popular radio stations nowadays operate in UHF frequencies. I know this was not the case in the past, long, medium and short wave radios much more popular (and AM encoding being quite popular vs nowadays FM, but in this case the reason is clear, noise levels vs device complexity).

What is the intrinsic property of UHF frequencies that give them an advantage over, say, long waves, so that it has gained so much popularity in radio?

Comment: As far as I know FM broadcasts are in the VHF, not in the UHF, range (but TV is). The primary advantage is that more bandwidth is available. But nowadays there is a shift to digital audio broadcasting (DAB) in the same range. The latter is somewhat more economical with bandwidth.

Comment: @Urgje: What is understood by bandwidth in relation to analog broadcasts? Frequency range occupied by a single broadcast (not to overlap a neighboring broadcast)? Or higher dynamic range of encodable audio, or something else yet? In digital it's clear, you can squeeze more data into the same channel, meaning multiple broadcasts or HD broadcast on a single frequency, but in analog?

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic: I seriously considered it, but I decided against - there's no actual electrical engineering in this question, just what is potentially a product of it. A bit like asking an Arquade question on Gamedev.SE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, a smaller antenna is able to transmit/receive the signals due to the low wavelength of such waves. Secondly, operating using high frequency supports a greater bandwidth as compared to the low frequency operation. Thirdly, the noise levels are much reduced in this domain as compared to the other.

There is one caveat however, you need more transmission power in order to compensate for the damping which increases with increase in frequency.

Comment: I believe the range loss due to higher power requirements is as much of a disadvantage as an advantage, allowing local radio stations to share the channel if separated by sufficient distance.

Comment: maybe. but from a physics viewpoint it is certainly disadvantageous.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "extra damping".  Radio engineers speak of "path losses", and as far as I know (I am not a radio engineer), the explanation of how path losses change as frequency changes are not simple.  Just for one small example, Some frequencies are less favorable for use in forested areas because they are more readily absorbed by foliage...

Comment: @jameslarge in any physical model, there will be model dependent characteristics. Therefore the model i am referring to is a general one, independent of internal sructure like forests etc.. i modified the term 'extra damping' in light of the apparent misunderstanding it was causing..thanks

Comment: @jameslarge look at the practical. Common coax transmission line transmits less energy at higher frequencies. To compensate you have to user large coax (more expensive and heaver [tower load limit considerations] ), or increase input power to the transmission line. There is a physical limit on how much power you can put in as the energy is usually lost as heat. The transmission line can dissipate only so much heat before its components break down and it ceases to function as a transmission line.